# Time counter for opening Maya file

Tags: python, maya, mel

I am trying to open an .mb file format, but it is taking pretty long to do so, in which I suppose the problem that is causing it is due to the amount of reference rigs in the file itself.

And hence, I was thinking, is there any sort of python/mel code that would states how long the file is being open?

Comment: What version are you using? As you open a file, in recent versions in the bottom left hand corner it will load in references individually and give you a progress bar?

Comment: I am using Maya 2012. As I opened my file, I am seeing no progress bar for some reasons. I do manage seeing it once, it gets stuck at 70% and stay there for quite a while. After that time, the area where the progress bar is, gets greyed out whenever I tried opening it

Comment: Does it eventually open? If not, I'd say you either have a corrupt file or you don't have enough memory

Comment: Yes it does eventually opens after 30-45 minutes or perhaps more.. However, I remember when we last open it, it takes about 5 minutes plus. Even so, is there any ways to check if it is the referencing files or whichever part in the Maya scene that is corrupted?

FYI, I tried to open/import the file without the reference rigs, it is still taking pretty long

Comment: Btw as I saved it as a `.ma` file, I found out that there seems to be a million plus of reference nodes that pops out of nowhere.. As I tried to delete/ using the Scene Optimaztion, either the Rigs does not load (Since I delete it manually for I got no idea which nodes do the rigs belongs to) or it hangs in the Optimazation process

Comment: maybe try and import that scene into a fresh one, sometimes this just clears out some bugs, give that a shot

Comment: You probably have tons of connections/overrides/edits in your scenes. The best is to export your animation curves, clean your references and reimport your animation,

Regarding your question, you could import your scene as "loadNone" then do a custom loading bar and increment the progress for each reference Maya loaded. You can also time each ones plus the actual Maya scene.